# how to check if the attribute of an instance is member of a queue in O(1)?

Tags: python, queue, priority-queue

I'm trying to design a Queue data structure with python 3.6

The queue has the aim to keep track node objects with these attributes:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, state, parent):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
```

**I want avoid to incorporate nodes with the same state in the queue.** So I design the following queue:

```
class queue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
        self.explored = set()

    def insert(self, element):
        self.list = [element] + self.list
        self.explored.add(str(element.state))
        return self.list

    def pop(self):
        oldest_element = self.list.pop()
        self.explored.remove(str(oldest_element.state))
        return oldest_element

    def empty(self):
       return len(self.list) == 0

    def check_member(self, other):
       return other in self.explored
```

In order to check if a state of a node is in the queue, I use the `check_member` method with the attribute state as a string type to see if is contained in the set with all the string state of the members. But this is still slowly.

**So it is possible to check if an instance has the same attribute of another instance that could differ in other attributes?** *For example, two nodes, same state attributes but different parents attributes.*

**How can keep the order of the elements and still checking if some element is in the queue in O(1) without using the additional explored set?**

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking. Do you want to avoid having the same state twice in your queue? Or solve the problem of removing the popped state from the set when there might be a second node with that same state in your queue?

Comment: I want avoid to incorporate nodes with the same state in the queue. I edit the question to clarify this part.

Comment: Do you want an attempt to add an existing state to fail loudly or just be ignored?

Comment: Just return False when use the attribute `check_member` in case of that state exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a set/dict type object to achieve `O(1)` contains-check complexity. The easiest would be to use an `OrderedDict` as your underlying data container. Use state as key and the node as the value. That way, the states are enforced to be unique, and the order is maintained nonetheless:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class queue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = OrderedDict()

    def insert(self, element):
        s = str(element.state)
        if s not in self.q:
             self.q[s] = element  # adds to the end

    def pop(self):
        return self.q.popitem(0)[1]  # returns the node from beginning

    def empty(self):
       return not self.q

    def check_member(self, element):
       return str(element.state) in self.q
```

Comment: I don't think u can check if an element is present or not using set type in O(1)

Comment: @Harry Not quite sure if I understand you. Firstly, my solution does not use a `set`. Secondly, `set` is designed for exactly that purpose: performantly storing and retrieving the information about the presence of an element.

Comment: "You need a set/dict type object to achieve O(1)". I don't think you can achieve O(1) with set type. As finding an object in set is O(n)

Comment: @Harry. No, it's not. In the worst case where all your elements have the same hash value, it might be. But with arbitrary data, the ammortized cost is `O(1)`. https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity
the worst timecomplexity of x in s is O(n) for set type. I am not stating about your answer but the statement. So may you edit.

Comment: You'll be hard pressed to find a real world case where you get close to `O(n)` for a set. You'd have accidentally or maliciously miscode the `__hash__` method of your data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155669/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-harry).

Comment: The part `if s not in self.q` is O(1)? Can you achieve the same with a standard dict if you don’t care about the order? And if the order matter, how can you achieve the ordered dict without using  `collections`?

Comment: 1. Yes, it is `O(1)`
2. Yes, you can
3. You can implement it yourself, but you will probably have to use multiple data structures nonetheless: a list for the order and a set for the contains-check. BTW, you should know that `self.list = [element] + self.list` or `list.insert(0, element)` is `O(N)`, too.

Comment: I see that the list is not the most efficient data structure for this, but the great advantage of the list is that is very straightforward to manipulate and keep the order. For example, how can you sort the dict based on a function?

Comment: Python's list is an array list which has O(1) append/remove at the end, but O(N) prepend/remove at the beginning. It is therefore not well suited for a queue which ideally has  O(1) operations on both ends. Look at [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) for such a container.